# Can I apply CSS to the elements within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, iframe

**I often see sites using iframes containing an external site, and a top frame containing JavaScript functionality for the user.**

e.g. user analytics software, Digg bar, etc...

---

Any tips for experimenting on something similar? =) Would be awesome to know

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, not from *outside* the iframe. An `<iframe>` is its own world. If the domains etc. match, then Javascript can communicate in and out, and could (if it wanted to) inject CSS into a child frame.

If the `<iframe>` contains content from a different domain, there's pretty much nothing you can do. The parent page controls the size of the frame and whether it's visible, and can put its own content *over* the frame by positioning etc, but it can't directly effect the way the actual frame content is rendered.

Comment: thanks so much! What if the domain is the exact same as the host page?

Comment: If you're on the same domain, then Javascript from the parent page can mess with the contents of the frame.  The parent page CSS won't affect the frame page, but Javascript can change the CSS or change element styles etc.

Comment: is there anyway to do this using some techniques people are saying.. embedding a child iframe or postMessage or something?

http://pipwerks.com/2008/11/30/iframes-and-cross-domain-security-part-2/

http://johan.driessen.se/posts/resizing-cross-domain-iframes

Answer (score 4):

If it is of same domain you can interfere the iframe content using javascript as follows..
assume id of iframe is `IframeId`. And you want to change color of element having id "elementId".

```
$("iframe").load(function() {
   var frameContents;
   frameContents = $("#IframeId").contents(); 
   frameContents.find("#elementId").css("color","#fff");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be accomplished by injecting the CSS link to the Header of the iframe:

```js
    // this function will inject the link to CSS into iframe header
    function loadCSSToiFrame(iframeId, filename){ 
       var file = document.createElement("link");
       file.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
       file.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
       file.setAttribute("href", filename);
       document.getElementById(iframeId).contentWindow.document.head.appendChild(file);
    }
  
    // just call a function to load your CSS
    // this path should be relative your HTML location
    loadCSS("iframe_id", "stylesheet.css");
```

Comment: This doesnt'w work -> cross-origin error