# Is it possible to change css of iframe if the iframe is not on the same domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Is it possible to change css of iframe if the iframe is not on the same domain? If it is, how is it possible to add css and change css, please help

```
<iframe id="frame1" width="100%" height="350" src="...." scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not.An `<iframe>` is its own world. If the domains etc. match, then Javascript can communicate in and out, and could (if it wanted to) inject CSS into a child frame.

**[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3286196/1719752)**

Answer (score 0):

No!

there was a function that writes a style-tag into the iframe after loading, but this doesnt work anymore.