# Fit a non-mobi web-site to a mobile browser

Tags: android, css, post, web, browser

I have a small project with one bureaucratic organisation where I need to create a mobile app based on data from their web-site. The site isn’t optimized for mobiles and it’s extremely difficult for users to use the site from their gadgets. The aim of the project is to provide information in convenient view and simplify the working processes of users (actually, I need to create 3 buttons/links and when a user press a button he/she can see some information).

The first button is easy to develop because it should only show news of the company which is shared for everyone. There are many opportunities to get this data and one of them is to get the source of the page and parse tags.

But, two other buttons is a pretty tough task, because to get the data for them a user should be logged on… Despite the company is very bureaucratic, the site was made by some outsource organisation, so neither they nor I have access to database and the site sources.

I tried to find out the type of POST request (recording tcp-dump), but, of course it’s encoded. I believe there’s a simpler solution, but I can’t find it, and need your help. Unfortunately, I’m not a web-developer and don’t know resources of web technology…

**Could you kindly advise me please, whether it’s possible to make some kind of a wrapper which would make dynamic design of web-page according to the browser? For instance, when a user presses one of these two buttons I show custom login screen (customized login screen of the company’s website, I virtually remove all design and make input fields and button bigger), the user provides details, press login button and I show customized view of a report (removing all needless stuff, etc.)**

In other words, just imagine, you're login to you gmail account which design of login page is customized [image: please look a picture]

After some manipulations with Chrome's element inspector you can get something like this [image]

Although the web page was modified, if I press "Sign in" button I still can login to my account. How can I get/develop similar tool for my android app?

Perhaps you have a better solution, please don’t hesitate to propose :) If my explanation of the problem isn’t clear just let me know please and I'll add some more information.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the reason nobody has answered yet is probably because your question is unclear. 
Do you have access to the code? If so, why don't you just insert a link to a css file in which you style the elements differently according to the size of the visitors browser? 
You can do this with Media Queries. You can use them to trigger certain parts of your css only when the visitors Browser/Screen size is lower or higher than a certain value. Use them to give out different css for smartphones, tablets, netbooks, desktops etc. Here you can see some good examples here: [Example of various media queries for responsive web design.](https://gist.github.com/staydecent/1021805)

I hope this helped you somehow.

Comment: Hi Jascha! Thank you for your answer! As i mentioned, the site was build by an outsource organisation and my company doesn't have access to sources, they even don't know the hoster :( I also updated my topic. 
If you modify a page with Chrome's element editor, the page still belongs to the website. So, i'm looking for some similar tool or idea, how I can develop it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Dennis! What you do with Chrome's element editor is, as you mentioned, only visible for you in your Browser. A permanent change visible to everyone can only be achived if you have access to the code. If it was possible to mess with external code, people would start to mess with other peoples websites. What you're trying to do is similar to this and the answer given there might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286178/can-i-apply-css-to-the-elements-within-an-iframe

Comment: Hi Jascha! Thank you for your answer! Yes, I no need a permanent solution, only a temporary one, perhaps for each session the page would be customized.
IFrame seems as a solution! I'll try to study it deeper and will write the result a bit later. Thanks again!